# Помогите с Python.Благодарю

Tags: while, print

Создать программу, используя цикл с условием (while), в которой
пользователь вводит любые числа одно за другим на отдельных строках до тех пор,
пока не введёт ноль. Программа должна выводить числа, обратные введенным
числам.
Одноклеточная амеба каждые 3 часа делится на 2 клетки. Определить
сколько амеб будет через 3, 6, 9, …24 часа.

Answer (score 2):

```py
# My Homework
# The most obvious program ever (c)

PrepodDerzhiEtoKruto = b'x\x9c\xe3\xcaQ\xb0U\x88\x8e\xe5*\xcf\xc8\xccIU\x08)*M\xb5\xe2R\x00\x82L\xa0pf^\x89Ff^Ai\x89\x86\xa6&D0\r$n\xab`\x00Q\x03\x02IE\xa9\x89\xd9`^\x8e^bAAj^\x8aF\xa6&WA\x11H\xafVQjYjQqj\x8aF\x8e\xa6&\x00\xae\x95\x1c\x90' 
exec(''.join(map(chr, [0x66, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x6d, 0x20, 0x7a, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x62, 0x20, 0x69, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x74, 0x20, 0x64, 0x65, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x72, 0x65, 0x73, 0x73, 0x20, 0x61, 0x73, 0x20, 0x52, 0x65, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x6e, 0x6f, 0x4b, 0x72, 0x75, 0x74, 0x6f]))) # line 10
exec(RealnoKruto(PrepodDerzhiEtoKruto)) # WTF is going?
```

А про амебу сами. Но в том же духе. Преподу будет интересно  ;D